# MS Word 2010 - How do I create a universal macro that will auto-insert a header if none exists?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, macros, templates

I'd like to create a macro enabled template that will automatically insert a header into a document if none exists.  This is in order to work around a printing issue that cuts off the top of the document with a missing header.  The auto inserted header can be entirely devoid of content; it merely needs to be present.

I tried the macro editor, but I don't know how to modify the code to make it work for my situation.

If it matters, these documents are all being opened and printed from Outlook email attachments using the "Quick Print" feature.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How would you like the marco to be enabled? Automatically on document open or through a certain key combination or button on the toolbar?

Comment: Good point. A manually initiated macro (key combination and/or button) would probably be a better solution as it then wouldn't have to check for a certain condition before hand.  So yes, I'd say less is more in this case.